# CouchDB view index performance

Tags: couchdb

I have some doubts about the best way to index my views.

Let's say I store documents that link "users" to "groups" like that:

```
{
  "groupId": "<group_id>",
  "userId": "<user_id>"
}
```

I want to retrieve all groups linked to a user, so obviously the best way to map it is:

```
emit(doc.userId, doc.groupId);
```

and I can retrieve the groups by querying the view with `key=<user_id>`.

But now if I want to delete the document corresponding to a specific user/group pair, I need to go through all the results of the view query until I hit the right value and get the document's ID.

So I thought that a better way of indexing the view would be like:

```
emit([doc.userId, doc.groupId], null);
```

Now I can get all groups linked to a user by issuing a range query and parsing the key of returned rows, and also hit directly a particular document (if it exists) with the "full" key. But I'm concerned that the range query (which will be called way more often than the "full" one) would have worse performances than the initial approach.

Any insight here would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the final answer is to measure whatever metrics are important to you.

However, I think the performance will be, roughly, the same. In each case, you will emit one view row per {user, group} pair.

Views can have multiple rows with the same "key." So when you query for `key=<user_id>` you are still doing a range query ("CouchDB, show me all view rows which start with user_id and end with user_id.") So I think you will see similar performance there.

To me, your biggest performance concern looks like latency: multiple round-trips to query this view, and then to follow up for the document. You can add `?include_docs=true` of course however that still adds additional i/o load. (In my opinion though, that extra cost is mostly theoretical, in real applications it is not so bad.)

To delete a document, you need more than the id. You need the revision too. So, to boost performance slightly and to reduce round-trips and latency, you could emit a more useful value instead of `null`. For example, emit the entire document! Or perhaps emit `{"_id":doc._id, "_rev":doc._rev}`. That way, you can delete the document "sight unseen" by issuing a DELETE to `/db/<id>?rev=<rev>`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think round-trips are a concern in my case, because the two queries are not related: it's either "get the list", or "(try to) delete an entry", but these are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should resist the urge to create too many tiny documents (which we bring with us from our SQL database experience). In this (admittedly example) use case either the list of users for a single group OR the list of groups for a single user could be a single document.

Clearly the users for a single group is highly likely to have multiple concurrent edits which leads to conflicts - but there is less likely to be multiple concurrent edits to the list of groups for a single user.

Therefore I advocate you create a single document per user listing their groups (or just add it as an array to some other user focused document). Use a fixed document ID scheme based on the user ID so you can access the document directly by ID without looking it up in a view. Now you just need to emit a view of users for a particular group.

If a user leaves a group you just update their group preferences. If a group is deleted you then have the chore of finding and removing the group ID from the preference of each of the groups members, but this will be a less frequent task, and typically only performed by an administrator who is more tolerant of a long running process.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I understand that you recommend not creating tiny documents and rather federate their data in single docs, but what's the actual downside of having many small docs?

Comment: The more documents you use to build a model the more you have to: a) add lots of views to bring them together and b) embed documentID's in them to create relationships (like a relational database but without the guarantees of relational integrity). CouchDB is a document store - you should be looking for ways to store complete structures as single documents for max benefits. The other problem with a high document count is that replication (especially the first time) takes forever as each document represents a GET.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. What you think you win by avoiding references to other documents you largely loose due to denormalization (what about if a user changes his name). It's not about tiny vs large documents, it's about proper aggregate design.

Comment: Yes and no. If  all the metadata for a user is on a single user document (for example) then if he changes his name it is changed on that same doc and there are NO references to worry about. Document datastores encourage denormalisation of data - if you fight that you might be better off with a relational database.